# Is json api for search only available for RT indices?

Tags: manticore-search

I tried to use '/json/search' api for a local plain index but encountered this error:

> "unknown local index(es) 'index_name' in search request"

Does manticore support json api for search on all types of indices?

Answer (score 1):

The API is available for all indexes. Are you sure that index 'index_name' exists?